# How to increase performance of store and load file

Tags: java, android, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I use this to store

```
FileOutputStream savedList = new FileOutputStream(....);
                GZIPOutputStream gz = new GZIPOutputStream(savedList);
                ObjectOutputStream oosList = new ObjectOutputStream(
                        gz);
                oosList.writeObject(input);

                oosList.close();
```

and this to load

```
 FileInputStream savedSerializable = new FileInputStream(....);

            GZIPInputStream gz = new GZIPInputStream(savedSerializable);
            ObjectInputStream oisList = new ObjectInputStream(
                    gz);
            savedList = (Serializable) oisList.readObject();
```

How could I increase speed of store and load?
Could `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` increase the performance? If yes, how should I use and configure these correctly(average file size is from 6 to 50mb)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Kryo (https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) which perform the serialization much faster and also reduce file size which also increase the speed of the total load/save.

**EDIT**

the following code will give you hints about how to use it

```
    Kryo k = new Kryo();
    Object[] input = new Object[]{/*...*/};

    //make serialization faster using code generation
    k.setAsmEnabled(true);
    //allow you to serializae objects of classes that does not have a default constructor
    k.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());

    //you should now register all the clsses types that you intend to use with kryo
    k.register(A.class);
    k.register(B.class);
    //...
    //now you can write your objects this way:
    try (ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DATA_STORE_LOCATION));
         Output out = new UnsafeOutput(zip)) {
        k.writeObject(out, input);
    }

    //and read it this way
    try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(DATA_STORE_LOCATION));
            Input in = new UnsafeInput(zip)){
        Object[] store = k.readObject(in, Object[].class);
    }
```

Comment: Could you give me a sample and more details about this? can affect RAM consumption?

Comment: @AndreaF see my updated answer, I believe that it will reduce the RAM consumption as it reading\writing less data and therefore use less memory
** note that i am not sure that the classes UnsafeInput and UnsafeOutput will work on android - you have different options in the library (FastInput / FastOutput) should work..

Comment: I get the error cannot resolve symbol at StdInstantiatorStrategy()

Comment: In addition get also a compilation error at `try (ZipInputStream....`relative to language, try with resource is supported in Java 7 that is supported only in android API level 19